# Can moderator or user with high reputation be held to the rules?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, down-votes, policy

I keep getting down voted instantly and as a quick as I flagged my last question it got denied without reason. Can moderator or a user with privileges be kicked for down voting to much? Is there a way to check who keeps instantly down voting me?

Comment: On this site 'moderator' means [these four users](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). If you do not mean that then please do not use that term - the correct word you're looking for is "user". Beyond the privileges that are [explicitly listed](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) in the help center, there is no distinction between someone with 100,000 reputation and someone with 100, and in particular both are subject to the same safeguards against serial voting as anyone else.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Somebody with 100 rep can't vote down anything, while somebody with 100k can give so many downvotes as he wants, + he can give close votes, and also delete votes. In addition, somebody with 100k practically can't be harassed by downvotes. In addition, somebody with 100k, has a significant spiritual power, what a 100 has not.

Comment: @peterh, no one, no matter their rep, can be harassed by downvotes *if* they *chose* not to be.  This is fact that *many* choose to evade.  And that's all I have to write about that.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes, but it requires to understand the system. For example, Jen's main problem are the downvotes, although his main problem should be the VtCs.

Comment: What is a "super user"? Can you point to the place in the help center or this meta where it is defined? If, on the other hand, you mean "high-reputation user" by that, then you *do* need to use the correct terms. That said, unless you have actual evidence that the downvotes come from any single user, you need to go way easier on your allegations. Have you seriously considered the possibility that your posts simply have deep flaws and are being downvoted by a broader set of users because of said flaws?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I corrected it thanks

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Mods can be de-modded if they violate their rules, but they do this only rarely. Although they are elected by the community, this election is lifelong, except if a Community Manager decides against it (or they retire, this is much more common). They can de-mod moderators any time. This all is very democratic.

Typically mods belong to the deletionist line of the sites, but they are following the majority opinions of the sites, which is also deletionist, at least on the big ones. It is the result of an unfortunate social selection mechanism: deciding about questions and voting to close them is quite boring after taking part in hundreds of such decisions, thus the only people doing this on the long-term is the few exceptions who enjoy it. This overweights the deletionist line on most sites.

But, in your case, not this is happened. Not the mods are harming you, simple users are harming you. As I understand, your main problem is the downvotes.

This harm is not really groundless. I am watching you, not because I want to vote you down, but because I want to make your questions salvageable. But it is hard, very hard, mainly because also I can't understand many of them.

Comment: What on earth is a "deletionist"? Also, the majority of questions is voted upon, closed or reponened without any mod involved whatsoever, so why are you calling that an "unfortunate social selection mechanism" for mods?

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1) Although the terminology originates from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Deletionism), now it describes the close&destruct mentality so common on the internet sites ruled by an inbreed inner circle. 2) The social selection mechanism I described isn't about the mods, it is about the reviewers. Only your comment focuses too strongly to the mods :-) (Btw, of course there is an indirect effect, that mostly the mods are coming mainly from the inner circle, which is already filtered by this mechanism, this is why also the mods are mostly deletionists).

Comment: Hint: "inbre[e]d" is an insult. Also, what is a "close&destruct mentality"? What has any of this to do with the downvotes on Jen's questions? Meta is not a place where you can freely rant about what you dislike about the site, you should *address the topic in the OP*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The OP names two problems in his questions: 1) he gets a lot of downs 2) he thinks he is intentionally bullied. 3) He has also a false suspection, that it is being done by the mods. My answer addresses all of them, and explains the context from a wider viewpoint. Thus there is no reason to delete this answer by its topic. There is reason to delete this answer because the majority of the down/vtc voters find the truth insulting.

Comment: I agree some of my answers are borderline, but a up and down vote should cost the voter a point just like in the comments. There are people who just down vote for the hell of it.

Comment: I've deleted a couple of off-topic comments.

Comment: @Jen It is because also this answer is downvoted. But listen to me: until you don't get 3-5 downs for all of your posts, you really don't have to worry. Even a single upvote on an answer compensates 5 downs, and 2.5 on a question. The effect of the downvotes are mainly a psychological pressure, so you can ignore it (btw, on the meta sites, the downs don't affect your reputation, so if you have here a really good post, and it is downvoted, it says actually more from the voters, as from you). What would be important: elevate the quality of your questions, make always detailed, well formatted

Comment: @Jen posts. Your native English can help a lot. Always consider: people reading your posts can't see your mind, they can only see what you wrote. It is better if you write what they already know, as if you miss something important. Explain this always, as if you would explain to somebody knowing nothing from your particular problem. Give also pictures, they can help a lot for others to understand what are you asking for. And, give to this whole text a clear format, separate it into paragraphs, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The main mechanism for the reversal of serial voting is automated, because the moderators have access only to summaries of inter-user voting, (not to detailed records) *even when our tools alert us to the existence of unusual patterns in voting*.

Alleging that the moderators aren't doing their job on this is simply silly: it's mostly not our job because the scripts take care of it. None-the-less I've looked into the findings of the automated system related to your account. I can assure you that the system has found no unusual pattern of downvoting directed at you.

I'll leave it to you to think up some alternative explanation for the large number of downvotes that you receive. Or you could ask for opinions in the chat room.

If you want to take this further, use the "[contact us](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link to be found at the bottom of every page: it will let you message the system wide moderation team directly.

Comment: Are there other users with some moderator privileges?

Comment: @Jen The employee of the SE, the Community Managers, and the programmers/sysadms. But not they and not the mods are harming you, simple users are voting you down because they don't like your posts. Some of them is really not high level, but you can improve a lot. The other of your posts are good.